# How to change the AppleID for retrieving profiles

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I've searched quite a bit - please let me know if this topic has been answered already.

I have worked in another team for a year or so. Now I'm working in a new team. I've set up certificates and profiles with the launch assistant on Apple's developer site. So far everything works fine. But when I now do a refresh from Xcode, Xcode seems to get the members and profiles of the old team. The new Profile shows up as an "unkown" team in the Organizer.

For me it looks like Xcode is liked to a wrong AppleID. How can I change this? Is there a place where I can log Xcode out from the old team, and then sign into the new one?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `Keychain Access` and go to the passwords section and delete passwords that are associated with Xcode or Apple Ex: `Apple ID Authentication`.

Once you've deleted the right keychain, Xcode will ask you to login and when it says "Would you like to save this to the keychain?" say no

Comment: thanks! But I cant find Apple ID Authentication? Is it in the login Keychain in the password cathegory? Thanks again.

Comment: It should be in the password category, "Apple ID Authentication" was just an example, you might find something else related to AppleID's that you need to remove

Comment: Found it. It's "daw2.apple.com" of kind "webform password". I closed Xcode, removed the entry from the keychain and viola, Xcode asked me for my user Apple ID. When refreshing, Xcode loaded the correct profiles etc.  Brilliant, thanks!